# Grep Regex: List all lines except

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

I'm trying to automagically remove all lines from a text file that contains a letter "T" that is  not immediately followed by a "H".  I've been using grep and sending the output to another file, but I can't come up with the magic regex that will help me do this.

I don't mind using awk, sed, or some other linux tool if grep isn't the right tool to be using.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

That should do it:

```
grep -v 'T[^H]'
```

-v : print lines not matching

[^H]: matches any character but H

Comment: Both instances of `.*` are not necessary, as grep scans the entire lines looking for a match

Answer (score 18):

You can do:

```
grep -v 'T[^H]' input
```

`-v` is the inverse match option of grep it does not list the lines that match the pattern.

The regex used is `T[^H]` which matches any lines that as a `T` followed by any character other than a `H`.

Answer (score 1):

Read lines from file exclude **EMPTY** Lines and Lines starting with **#**

```
grep -v '^$\|^#' folderlist.txt
```

folderlist.txt

```
# This is list of folders
folder1/test
folder2
# This is comment
folder3

folder4/backup
folder5/backup
```

Results will be:

```
folder1/test
folder2
folder3
folder4/backup
folder5/backup
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding 2 `awk` solutions to the mix here.

---

---

***1st solution(simpler solution):*** With simple `awk` and any version of `awk`.

```
awk '!/T/ || /TH/' Input_file
```

**Checking 2 conditions:**

- If a line doesn't contain `T` OR
- If a line contains `TH` then:

  If any of above condition is TRUE then print that line simply.

---

---

***2nd solution(GNU `awk` specific):*** Using GNU `awk` using `match` function where mentioning regex `(T)(.|$)` and using `match` function's array creation capability.

```
awk '
!/T/{
  print
  next
}
match($0,/(T)(.|$)/,arr) && arr[1]=="T" && arr[2]=="H"
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** firstly checking if a line doesn't have `T` then print that simply. Then using `match` function of `awk` to match `T` followed by any character OR end of the line. Since these are getting stored into 2 capturing groups so checking if array arr's 1st element is T and 2nd element is H then print that line.